# app crashes the first time i run cucumber after i reset the simulator on iOS

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash-ios

i get the following error when i run cucumber for the first time after i reset the simulator on iOS:

```
Could not parse response ''; the app has probably crashed (RuntimeError)
```

the second scenario also fails with the following error:

```
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
When I setup credentials without password                                 # features/step_definitions/setup_steps.rb:10
  Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 37265 (http://localhost:37265) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

am i doing something wrong- or is running the app once in xcode before running cucumber the way it is supposed to be done?

Comment: the app opens correctly, and the first is even executed properly, before the app crashes.

Comment: Are you just running the tests using `cucumber`? Or are you passing using any environment variable?

Comment: no variables are being passed- i am just running cucumber.

Comment: also, if i run cucumber once more, the error does not persist. in the same way, if i run the app once on xcode and then run cucumber, the problem does not occur either.

Comment: What happens if you reset the Simulator, run the app from Xcode, and do the same steps the `feature` specifies? (I don't have an answer yet, just trying to gather more information)

Comment: if i run the app once on xcode and then run cucumber, the problem does not occur either. does that mean that i have to run the app once before cucumber will work?

Comment: @shreyasSV that is possible, especially if you are cleaning your build/DrivedData folder and/or making updates to the app.

Comment: @adam no changes were made to the app and i am not cleaning the build- just reset the simulator and run cucumber. anyways, we have decided to simply run the app in xcode once and then run cucumber. can we close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was hoping someone else would give an answer that i could use to close the thread, but since they did not, let me do it-
we used to have problems with calabash crashing when we reset the simulator before we updated calabash to 14.

we had decided to simply run the app on xcode once after resetting the simulator, but now, even that is not required.
the issue is therefore a non-issue.